# If an MV is a degree of freedom, is there a way to force the optimizer to move it at least a certain amount or not at all?

Tags: gekko

In an MPC application, sometimes the optimizer will make the decision of moving a valve by 0.2% on a possible scale of 0-100%. Rather than moving valves a very small amount (which is not really contributing that much besides adding movement to the valves) I would like the optimizer to only move the valve if it will go above a certain threshold (say 5%). So, only if the optimizer would move the valve >= 5% would it make the decision to move the valve.

`DMAX`, `DMAXHI`, and `DMAXLO` can prescribe how much you can move the variable, but do not prevent insignificant movements. There is always the option of clipping the output of the optimizer, but it would be more ideal if the optimizer could factor it into its prediction.

Because this is a real-time application, the solution cannot contain binary integer variables that would slow down the solution time.

Comment: It seems like this would be a valuable MPC feature in the case of valve stiction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiction) where you can command a certain movement of a valve but it only finally moves once the change is beyond a certain threshold. Are you trying to model valve stiction or is it because the operator wants more periods of no movement? Move suppression factors are in MPC applications such as DMC and GEKKO but this isn't the right solution to guarantee the minimum threshold that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible method is to use a hierarchical approach where you repeatedly solve the problem and fix the value of MVs that don't move appreciably:

1. Solve the optimization problem and identify which MVs have moved but not enough to be outside the threshold for insignificance
2. Turn off the status for those MVs and fix them at their previous values
3. Re-solve the problem, and then check for any additional MVs that have moved but not enough to be significant

You can repeat this cycle as many times as you'd like depending on the number of MVs you have and the time it takes to solve your optimization problem. Depending on how frequently you need to solve it, this approach could be a viable strategy, and is likely to be faster than using a MINLP solver.